# Pivot without aggregate - again

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table where I want to pivot some rows.  There are lots of these questions on here, but I am still struggling.

Here is the table that I am starting from.
[image: Starting Point]

Here is where I want to get to
[image: Ending Point]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you can easily get the result using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select userlicenseid,
  startdate,
  max(case when name = 'Other' then value end) Other,
  max(case when name = 'Pathways' then value end) Pathways,
  max(case when name = 'Execution' then value end) Execution,
  max(case when name = 'Focus' then value end) Focus,
  max(case when name = 'Profit' then value end) Profit
from yourtable
group by userlicenseid, startdate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ec0a/1). Since you are converting string values into columns, then you will want to use either the `min()` or `max()` aggregate.

You could use the PIVOT function to get the result as well:

```
select userlicenseid, startdate,
  Other, Pathways, Execution, Focus, Profit
from
(
  select userlicenseid, startdate,
    name, value
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for name in (Other, Pathways, Execution, Focus, Profit)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ec0a/2)